# Multiple Document Ready Functions (/w and /wo callbacks)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am running multiple functions that I require the document to be ready for. I have a question surrounding the use of

```
$(function()
{
    funA();
});
```

1) Which of the following is technically correct:

(a) I presume because it's scope is limited to the initial function within it's braces.

```
    $(function()
    {
        funA(function()
        {
            $(function()
            {
                funB(function()
                {
                    $(function()
                    {
                        funC();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

vs

(b) I presume because it's scope applies to all functions within it's braces.

```
    $(function()
    {
        funA(function()
        {
            funB(function()
            {
                funC();
            });
        });
    });
```

(c)

neither (please elaborate).

2) Does the method differ if callbacks are not being used?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean by your question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My code works, I just wish to avoid unnecessary overhead. In short: is it necessary to call $(function(){ }); for every function that should be executed on document ready or is it sufficient enough to use $(function(){ }); once and it'll apply to all functions called within it's braces.

Comment: Why would you nest document ready functions? If the parent function is in document ready, the nested functions are per definition ready too?

Comment: The nesting is due to callbacks, there is probably a better way of doing it (possibly) but it's just the way I wrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the question is "how `$(f);` works".

When `$(f)` (or its full form `$(document).ready(f)`) is called, jQuery basically checks if the document is already loaded.

1. If it is already loaded, `f()` is immediately **queued** for execution after the current code completes.
2. If it is not yet loaded, `f` is **added** to the list of functions to be queued when the appropriate event is detected by jQuery.

Because of that, it's safe-ish* to call `$(f)` nested inside a callback, but unnecessary, as the top-level callback is guaranteed to to execute only after the event happened, and nested callbacks cannot execute sooner than the function to which it is passed.

---

* - I say "safe-ish", because the callback of `$()` is never executed immediately but only queued; this can lead to potentially unwanted results.

```
$(f);
g();
```

will always see `g()` executed before `f()`. This does not apply to your question, but I felt like pointing it out anyway.